# vb.net Google api for device authentication simple http post request fail

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

I am creating a google drive device application.
And I am trying to go through the tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

and I got stock on the frist Step the simple POST

this return 400 bad request:

```
  Try

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim data As StringBuilder
        Dim byteData() As Byte
        Dim postStream As Stream = Nothing
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        data = New StringBuilder()
        data.Append("client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&")
        data.Append("scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive")
        byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString())
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Try
            postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        Finally
            If Not postStream Is Nothing Then postStream.Close()
        End Try

        Try
            ' Get response  
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            ' Get the response stream into a reader  
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

            ' Console application output  
            tb1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Finally
            If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        tb1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
```

Am i missing posting information? is is an httpwebrequest not the right tool?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write your own authorization, you can use the .NET client library. We have [examples here](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials) for c# and you should easily be able to translate them to VB.NET.

Comment: the problem is this is for a limited access application device the the authentication url must be done on an other computer using "http://www.google.com/device" where user type a code he is given.